# Understanding tomcat's context.xml config file

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat7, c3p0, sessionfactory

I have `context.xml` file in `tomcat/conf` folder:

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>      
    <Resource 
        auth="Container" 
        description="DAPS Database" 
        driverClass="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"      
        testConnectionOnCheckin="true" 
        idleConnectionTestPeriod="300" 
        maxIdleTime="240"
        minPoolSize="3" 
        maxPoolSize="20" 
        acquireIncrement="1" 
        name="jdbc/stem" 
        user="dbuser" 
        password="p@ssword" 
        factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" 
        type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" 
        jdbcUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://000.000.0.00/stem;user=dbuser;password=p@ssword;TDS=8.0" 
    />  
  <Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```

My application's `WEB-INF` `application-context.xml` file:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/stem</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Hibernate properties to be used in the Session Factory -->
    <bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">1000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">4</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">1000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <ref bean="hibernateProperties" />
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>      
              <value>mil/dla/daps/model/businessobject/login/Address.hbm.xml</value>                    
               <value>mil/dla/daps/model/businessobject/login/State.hbm.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory">
                <ref local="sessionFactory" />
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Can someone shed some light on why would someone use these values:

- type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
- driverClass="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
- factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"

and if this should match my application's `application-context.xml` file

The reason I am looking into this and trying to understand what's going on, is because Tomcat is constantly hanging if it gets hit by 30+ users and is eating up all of the resources.

Looking at the db server, I see hundreds of TCP connections coming from Tomcat's server.